# How to use if statement using awk

Tags: awk

```
input.txt
IP 10.10.10.1
```

```
IPCHK=$(cat input.txt | awk '/IP/ {print $2}')
if [[ $IPCHK =~ 10.* ]] ; then
echo " $IPCHK "
else
echo " IP Not Match "
fi
```

Can someone help to convert above shell script to awk script ?

Thanks,

Comment: Tell us what it's supposed to do with sample input and expected output. You can't post a script that doesn't do whatever it is you want and expect us to guess what you do want a script to do.

Comment: I have a list of IP addresses where I would need to find out the IP starts with 10.* series. just thought of a one liner with awk using the BEGIN method.

Comment: Edit your question to provide the details (again, including sample input and expected output), don't try to put it in comments where you cant format them.

Comment: Do you have more than on IP in `input` file.  If so, would you like to list the line number and IP of lines with IP not starting with `10`

Comment: @user3834663 `the IP starts with 10.*` could mean one of several different things so be sure when you create your sample input file to provide similar-looking cases you do NOT want to have match as it's always trivial to match what you do want but much harder to exclude what you dont want.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
cat input.txt
IP 10.10.10.1
```

```
awk '/IP/ {print ($2~/^10\./?$2:"IP Not Match") }' input.txt
10.10.10.1
```

and

```
cat input.txt
IP 12.10.10.1
```

```
awk '/IP/ {print ($2~/^10\./?$2:"IP Not Match") }' input.txt
IP Not Match
```

---

Here is some more example:

```
cat input.txt
Data
IP 10.10.10.1
Bla
Bla
IP 12.10.20.1
More
```

```
awk '/IP/ {print $2,($2~/^10\./?"OK":"IP Not Match")" Line "NR }' input.txt
10.10.10.1 OK Line 2
12.10.20.1 IP Not Match Line 5
```

PS Do not use `cat` with programs that can read data itself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you have *two* conditions you want to match against, and don't know how to AND them.

Before I actually answer your question, let me just point out that the regex `10.*` matches "10.1.2.3", but also "102.3.4" and "210abcde".  The `.*` bit means "any number of any character", it's not a wildcard the way you think.  If you want to use a regex to match an RFC1918 IP address, you need to be more specific.  This should do:

```
^(10\.[0-9]+|192\.168|172.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$
```

So... Based on your example, it looks as if an empty `$IPCHK` variable is fine as long as there's an error message, so something like this might work:

```
IPCHK="$(awk '/^IP 10\./ {print $2}' input.txt)"
if [ -n "$IPCHK" ]; then
  echo " $IPCHK "
else
  echo " IP Not Match "
fi
```

Alternately you can actually AND two tests:

```
IPCHK="$(awk '$1=="IP" && $2~/10\./ {print $2}' input.txt)"
                       ~~
```

And if you want the error messages inside awk as well, this might work for you:

```
IPCHK="$(awk '
           $1=="IP" {
             if($2~/^10\./) {
               print $2;
             } else {
               print "IP NOT MATCH" > "/dev/stderr";
             }
           }' input.txt)"
```

I've spread this out for easier reading, but you can remove the newlines to make it a one-liner.